# Failed to create socket error node sequelize

Tags: node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

Im using sequelize. My database is running on a VDS. Sometimes im getting this error. But its not happening while im starting the app. It happens after some queries. Sometimes after 10 queries, sometimes after 500 queries. Its not predictable. i dont know why. How can i increase the timeout ? Or how can i fix it ?

```
text: 'Connection timeout: failed to create socket after 1010ms',
sql: null,
fatal: true,
errno: 45012,
sqlState: '08S01',
code: 'ER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
```

My code ;

```
  const { host, port, user, password, database, poolMax, poolMin, dialect, acquire, idle } = config.database;
  const connection = await mariadb.createConnection({
    host: host,
    port: port,
    user: user,
    password: password,
    database: database,
    multipleStatements: true,
  });
  await connection.query(`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`${database}\`;`);

  // connect to db
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, user, password, {
    host: host,
    port: port,
    dialect: 'mariadb',
    operatorsAliases: false,
    timeout: 10000,
    dialectOptions: {
      options: {
        requestTimeout: 60000,
        connectTimeout: 60000
      }
    },
    pool: {
      max: 10,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000,
    }
  });
```

Comment: You should add details about your environment, where the database is running? What is your pool settings?

Comment: Increase `min` to 2, why do you need `acquire` and `idle`?

Comment: I dont remember why i added acquire and idle. Whats gonna change if i increase poolMin to 2 ? Do you think its the problem ?

Comment: You didn't add any details about your environment, so I can only guess.

Comment: Which details do you need ? I added the details about the environment.

Comment: Hello, I am facing the same issue - if you find the fix please tell me